# Azure Application Insight wrong shows URL in logs for ASP.NET Core 6 Web API application with API versioning

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

I have an ASP.NET Web API application running on .NET 4.8. In this app, I'm using standard Microsoft API versioning from `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning` and `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning.ApiExplorer`.

For instance:

```
[ApiVersionExtended(SupportedApiVersions.V9)]
[RoutePrefix("v{version:apiVersion}/telemetry")]
public sealed class TelemetryController : ApiController
{
```

where `ApiVersionExtended` - my filter. In Azure Application Insight requests to my API are shown with the correct version. For instance:

[image]

But after migration to .NET 6, I lost the correct version number in AI logs, for instance:

[image]

My code has several changes after migration to .NET 6

```
[ApiController]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ApiVersionExtended]
[Route("v{version:apiVersion}/telemetry")]
public sealed class TelemetryController : ApiController
{
  [HttpGet("ipInfo")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> GetIpInfoAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    /* some code here */
  }
}
```

I can't find the analog `[RoutePrefix]` attribute in .NET 6.

Might someone know what the reason for this issue is? And how I can fix it?

Comment: So the url in application insights still shows the correct value but the name of the operation is different. That could also be caused by an update of the application insights NuGet package.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Peter Bons, this can be the issue with your existing Nuget Package.

- The Nuget Package required to Implement API Versioning in .NET 6 Core Web API is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning`
- Install **`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning`** Nuget Package

[image]

In `Program.cs` add the below services

***To add versioning for `WebAPI`***

```cs
builder.Services.AddApiVersioning(opt =>
{
    opt.DefaultApiVersion = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiVersion(2, 0);
    opt.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    opt.ReportApiVersions = true;
    opt.ApiVersionReader = ApiVersionReader.Combine(new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader(),
                                                    new HeaderApiVersionReader("x-api-version"),
                                                    new MediaTypeApiVersionReader("x-api-version"));
});
```

***To Add versioning with Swagger, add the below services***

```cs
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(Options => Options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Audit Self Serve platform", Version = "v1" }));
```

Use `MapToApiVersion` attribute to assign each action to a distinct version

```cs
[MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
[HttpGet]
```

***OutPut:***
[image]